# How to fetch multiline with ExtractGrok processor in ApacheNifi?

Tags: apache-nifi, logstash-grok, grok

I am going to convert a log file events (which is recorded by `LogAttribute` processor) to JSON.

I am using `ExtractGrok` with this configuration:

[image]

STACK pattern in pattern file is `(?m).*`

Each log has this format:

```
2019-11-21 15:26:06,912 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-4] org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.LogAttribute LogAttribute[id=143515f8-1f1d-1032-e7d2-8c07f50d1c5a] logging for flow file StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=02eb9f21-4587-458b-8cee-ad052cb8e634,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1574339166853-1, container=default, section=1], offset=0, length=0],offset=0,name=0df20cc1-3f93-49df-81b1-dac18318ccd9,size=0]
------------- request was received----------
Standard FlowFile Attributes
Key: 'entryDate'
    Value: 'Thu Nov 21 15:26:06 AST 2019'
Key: 'lineageStartDate'
    Value: 'Thu Nov 21 15:26:06 AST 2019'
Key: 'fileSize'
    Value: '0'
FlowFile Attribute Map Content
Key: 'filename'
    Value: '0df20cc1-3f93-49df-81b1-dac18318ccd9'
Key: 'http.context.identifier'
    Value: '9552bd22-ec3b-4ada-93a9-a5ce9b27de25'
Key: 'path'
    Value: './'
Key: 'uuid'
    Value: '02eb9f21-4587-458b-8cee-ad052cb8e634'
-------------- request was received----------
```

I expect rest of the message after first line saved in log, but I get only first line:

```
-------------- request was received----------
```

I check the expression in [Grok Debugger](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) and it works. but it doesn't work with NiFi.

How to config ExtractGrok to get all lines in log value?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, I replace `(?m).*` with this one `(?s).*` and it works.