# How to use NiFi ExtractGrok properly

Tags: logstash, apache-nifi, logstash-grok

I'm using: NiFi v1.8.0 and Logstash v7.1.1

I'm tasked to move all our Logstash configurations over to NiFi. I am trying to understand how the NiFi ExtractGrok works, but I can't find any examples. How is this intended to be used? And how can you set a NiFi attribute with this grok processor? And when I mean examples, I mean actual examples that show you a before and after so people can understand whats going on. I've read the NiFi ExtractGrok documentation, but its very limited and seems to assume you understand how it works.

This is the only example I've been able to find: [How to fetch multiline with ExtractGrok processor in ApacheNifi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58981203/how-to-fetch-multiline-with-extractgrok-processor-in-apachenifi)

Answer (score 2):

According to what you are saying, the processor you need, is rather [ConvertRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.8.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ConvertRecord/index.html) than `ExtractGrok`. `ExtractGrok` will only extract certain fields into FlowFile attributes or content.

If you want to **format your log files** into a workable format(like JSON, if you want to send those files to ElasticSearch), then you would use **[GrokReader](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-record-serialization-services-nar/1.8.0/org.apache.nifi.grok.GrokReader/index.html)** as `Record Reader` and `Record Writer` as [JsonRecordSetWriter](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-record-serialization-services-nar/1.8.0/org.apache.nifi.json.JsonRecordSetWriter/index.html).

Then, you would configure your `Schema Text` (or use a Schema Registry) in both `RecordReader` and `RecordWriter` to be your schema, and set `Grok Expression` to be your grok expression in your `GrokReader`.

**For example:**

my log messages log like this:

```
2019-12-09 07:59:59,136 this is the first log message
2019-12-09 09:59:59,136 this is the first log message with a stack trace: org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator - DataSource health check failed
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:81)......
```

So, my grok would be:
`%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\s+%{GREEDYDATA:log_message}`

and my schema would be:

```json
{
  "name": "MyClass",
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "com.acme.avro",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "timestamp",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "log_message",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "stackTrace",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note the `stackTrace` field I've added to the schema. The `GrokReader` automatically maps stack traces into their own field. So you have to add `stackTrace` field if you want to map it too. Then, you can put it into the `log_message` field if you want, using Jolt.
The output of this `ConvertRecord` would be:

```json
[
  {
    "timestamp": "2019-12-09 07:59:59,136",
    "log_message": "this is the first log message",
    "stackTrace": null
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2019-12-09 09:59:59,136",
    "log_message": "this is the first log message with a stack trace: org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator - DataSource health check failed",
    "stackTrace": "org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)\nat org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:81)......"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at this now.

Comment: Are there docs on how to build a schema? I'm confused what "name", "type", and "namespace" are for. The Fields makes sense, but can this handle fields you don't expect or do you have to specify each field?

Comment: Avro Schema is for defining how your record should look like. You can generate an avro Schema out of a Json here: https://toolslick.com/generation/metadata/avro-schema-from-json